# How to add values to jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and finding it difficult to add values to my code.
I want it so the slider skips to a number when you scroll it, such as:
25,000 | 50,000 | 75,000 or 6500, 14000, 28000, 50000 how would I go about it?

```
$(function() {
$( ".slider.gems" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 99999,
    value: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".number.gems" ).text( ui.value );
    }
});
$( ".number.gems" ).text( $( ".slider.gems" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `step` property to snap to increments - like this:

```
$(function() {
$( ".slider.gems" ).slider({
    step: 25000,
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 99999,
    value: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".number.gems" ).text( ui.value );
    }
});
$( ".number.gems" ).text( $( ".slider.gems" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did it another way... 

`$(function() {
 var valMap = [6500, 14000, 28000, 50000];
 $( ".slider.gems" ).slider({
      max: valMap.length - 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
       $(".number.gems").text(ui.value);
            $(".number.gems" ).text(valMap[ui.value]);
         }
    });
 $( ".number.gems" ).text( $( ".slider.gems" ).slider( "value" ) );
});`

Comment: If I wanted to do:
6500, 14000, 28000, 50000

how would I go about it?